# store $http GET promise object locally

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I've been scratching my head trying to figure out how to implement a simple data update on my graph due to my lack of Angular service knowledge. All I am trying to is make one GET request and store the JSON object locally on my controller so that I can have (1) the original JSON to render the original chart and (2) a modified JSON based on user input (always modifies the original JSON) to render the updated chart. Here is my controller:

`

```
angular.module('scattChartApp')
.controller('ChartCtrl', function($scope, $http, $cacheFactory) {

  $http.get('chartConfig.json').success(function(response) {
    $scope.options = response.options;
    $scope.data = response.data;
    $scope.initData = angular.copy($scope.data);
  });



  $scope.update = function(user){
    var a, b, c, d, e;
    a = user.a; b = user.b; c = user.c; d = user.d; e = user.e;
    var data = $scope.data;
    if(a !== "" && b !== "" && c !== "" && d !== "" && e !== ""){
      for(var i = 0; i<$scope.data.length; i++){
          for(var j = 0; j<$scope.data[i].values.length; j++){
              var x = $scope.data[i].values[j].x;
              var y = $scope.data[i].values[j].y;
              var z = $scope.data[i].values[j].size;
              data[i].values[j].x = a*x + b*y;
              data[i].values[j].y = c*x + d*y;
              data[i].values[j].size = e*e*z;
          }
      }
      $scope.$apply();
    }
  };

  $scope.reset = function(){ 
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.data = angular.copy($scope.initData);
    $scope.$apply();
  }; 

});`
```

This is my plunker (which if you make a proper input and press update will scale accordingly but only 1 time and the rest won't work): http://plnkr.co/edit/n4bDl7LYoylW5tWbRA6g?p=preview

Comment: Those `$scope.$apply()` should be removed. This function is designed to be called within ellements that don't come from the Angular framework.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `$scope.$apply()` should solve the problem.

Since all the functions you are using here come from the AngularJS framework, you don't have to use `$scope.$apply()`. In fact it's even making your application crash. That's probably why it's working only once.

For more informations about `$scope.$apply()`[AngularDoc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)

**Edit:**
It's possible you need to set the plugin option refreshDataOnly to false.

Comment: No sorry, neither of these suggestions apply. $scope.$apply() was there just as reassurance but taking it away certainly doesn't allow the ability to copy the response object to a global variable (local within controller). refreshDataOnly = true simply allows the chart update with transitions